# Eventually add to List

Tags: scala

Let's say I have a function returning an immutable Map (`getMap` below) and I have two options and I I want to add an entry to the map if the option is set, otherwise leave the map unmodified.

So in non-functional code (like you would write it in java):

```
  def getMap(): Map[String, String] = {
    Map(
      "name" -> "My Name",
      "age" -> "80")
  }


  def testJavaLink() {
    val o1: Option[String] = Some("This one is set")
    val o2: Option[String] = None

    var mutableResult: mutable.Map[String, String] = mutable.Map() ++ getMap()
    if (o1.isDefined) {
      mutableResult("option1") = o1.get
    }

    if (o2.isDefined) {
      mutableResult("option2") = o2.get
    }

    val result: Map[String, String] = mutableResult.toMap
  }
```

This code is obviously not very scala-like, so I tried to do it using map-functions:

```
  def test1() {
    val o1: Option[String] = Some("This one is set")
    val o2: Option[String] = None

    val result: Map[String, String] = getMap() ++ (if (o1.isDefined) List(("option1", o1.get)) else List()) ++ (if (o2.isDefined) List(("option2", o2.get)) else List())
  }
```

But this code is horrible readable.

How can I achieve something similar using readable scala? For lists there is a nice syntax (which makes use of the fact that a Option can be turned into a Iterable which has either one or zero elements). But I don't know how to make use of this when using maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
val result = getMap ++ o1.map("option1" -> _) ++ o2.map("option2" -> _)
```

### Why does this work?

`->` just creates a `Tuple2` (a *pair*)

So `o1.map("option1" -> _)` returns an `Option[(String,String)]` which is `None` if `o1` was `None` and which is `Some(("option1", value))` otherwise.

Finally, `Option[A]` can be implicitly converted to an `Iterable[A]` which is empty if `Option[A]` is `None` and which is a `List[A]` containing only one element otherwise. Therefore `Option[(String,String)]` gets converted to `Iterable[(String,String)]`. And the latter can be added to your `Map[String,String]` using `++`.

Comment: Nice, didn't think about `Option` being traversable.

Comment: Could you explain in easy words why this works? What does .map on a Option do? And is `"option1" -> variable1` equivalent to `Map("option1" -> variable)` and just a shorthand?

Comment: I added the explanation in my answer. I hope it is clearer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can `map` the `Option`s to a `Tuple` then call `toMap` and `++`:

```
  val o1: Option[String] = Some("This one is set")
  val o2: Option[String] = None

  val result = getMap ++ o1.map(o => ("option1", o)).toMap ++ o2.map(o => ("option2", o)).toMap
```

Comment: More concisely you could use `o1.map("option1".→)` and similarly for `o2`